# Country Dropdown, but country is automatically selected based off on their country

Tags: javascript, html

I found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324069/automatic-dropdown-based-on-country-with-geoplugin), but it uses jquery and geoplugin which I'm not familiar with, and does something different than I'm trying to do. You see, I have a country dropdown selector in my HTML code, and I want the country that the user lives in to be automatically selected. And assuming we have access to what country they live in, I've seen this on websites that I don't allow my location to. The post linked above just tells you what country you live in, rather than selecting it in the dropdown for you.

Comment: They're using an IP geolocation service, which gets the country from your IP address.

Comment: What's your question? Whatever way you get the user's country, use that to set the value of the dropdown.

Comment: @Barmar it's more of jquery, if i installed jquery would it put a lot of extra information nd size onto my project? and then how would I actually get the country on the input to be selected of that country, because I have a <select> with many <options>

Comment: jQuery makes little difference. Vanilla JS: `document.getElementById("countrySelector").value = country;` jQuery: `$("#countrySelector").val(country)`

Comment: Getting the country is pretty much the same with vanilla JS and jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar i see, thank you, so it can be possible to do that in vanilla JS? Ill find a way to do that